# Group Theory proof question

Tags: group-theory

I'm stuck on this proof, any help would be appreciated

Show that, for all $n\in \mathbb{Z}$, $a^n=a^{n-1}a$

I used the fact that its true for positive $n$ by definition and proved true for $n=0$ but for negative $n$, I wasn't able to prove
$a^m(a^{-m-1})a=e$ after letting n=-m. whereas $(a^{-m-1})aa^m=e$ was fine.

Comment: What is the definition of $a^n$?  I'm not sure with what definition this can be proven with any thing other than $a^n = a^{n-1}*a$ because $n-1 + 1 = n$ and $a^n$ means "multiply $a$ by itself $n$ times".

Comment: in my group theory course our book says by definition a^n=a^(n-1)*a for positive n, so we could use that without proof in exercises for now..which could be proved by induction I think though right

Comment: Is $a^{-m}$ defined as $(a^{-1})^m$?  Then just for $-m$ let $b= a^{-1}$ and so $a^{-m}*a = b^m*a = b^m*b^{-1}$ which you've proven is $b^{m-1}*b*b^{-1} = b^{m-1} = a^{-m + 1}$.   Done.

Comment: How did the book define $a^{-k}$?

Comment: yep like you said above

Comment: @fleablood quick question if we have two group and question asked show 1 is subset of other , could I show one is subgroup of other and that'll complete proof?

Comment: Since a subgroup must be a subset, yes.  But I'm not really sure how you'd prove something is a subgroup without showing it is a subset first.

Comment: just showing closure , identity and inverse laws I thought

Comment: Well, that will show it is a group but to show it is a subgroup you have to show that no elements of the subgroup are *not* in the super group.  I.e. it is a subset.  That *could* be easier if you can show $a, b$ are shared elements and if they are both groups then all combinations of $a$ and $b$ are in both groups and you dont have to check them all but you do, one way or another, have to show if $a$ is in the smaller group, then it is also in the bigger group.

Comment: true! like lets say group S={$a^k/k \in_{z}$} we can easily show its a subgroup of G if a $\in _{G}$ but how are we sure its a subgroup? sorry editing skills still not on point:p

Comment: I meant subset sorry "are we sure its a subset..."

Comment: In that case, yes.  If $a \in G$ and $G$ is a group then $a^k \in G$ for all $k$.  So $S \subset G$ and so as $S$ is a group it is a subgroup.

Comment: thanks , also  $a^m*a^n=a^{m+n}=a^n*a^m$ is true right? does this require a proof

Comment: You can prove that with induction.  If $n >0$ then $a^m*a^n = a^m*a*a^{n-1} = a^{m+1}a^{n-1}$.  Then for $n < 0$ let $b = a^{-1}$ and the result follows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $n \ge 1$

$a^{n-1}*a = a^n$ by definition.

If $n = 0 $ then $a^{-1}$ is the multiplicative inverse and $a^{-1}*a = e = a^0$.

If $n < 0$ then $n = -m$ for some $m> 0$.  And $a^{n} = a^{-m} = (a^{-1})^m$.

Let $b = a^{-1}$.

So..... $a^{n-1}*a = a^{-m - 1}*a = b^{m+1}*a = b^m*(b*a)= b^m = a^{-m} = a^{n}$.

Comment: thanks a lot bro :)

Answer (score 0):

If $n \in \mathbb{Z}_{< 0}$, then $a^n=\left(a^{-n}\right)^{-1}=\left(a^{-n+1}\cdot a^{-1}\right)^{-1}=a\cdot(a^{-n+1})^{-1}=a\cdot a^{n-1}$.

Comment: could we use the fact that $(ab)^{-1}=b^{-1}a^{-1}$ without proof?

Comment: Is this for a class? If you've proven it in class, then yes.

Comment: yeah it is , thanks